# NUnit: test if two collections are equivalent and only report the difference

Tags: c#, nunit

I am using NUnit to assert the following:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new[] {"a", "b", "c"}, new[] {"b", "a", "d"});
    }
```

This yields the following error message:

> Expected: equivalent to < "a", "b", "c" >
>
> But was:  < "b", "a", "d" >

That's okay for this trivial example. However, when there are more elements and/or longer, harder to distinguish strings, the error message doesn't help to see what's going on.

I was expecting to have (maybe additionally) something like:

> Missing: "c"
>
> Extra: "d"

Are there any means of achieving this using NUnit? (I could of course go and program something on my own but that's not the question here.)

Comment: No, this is what's built-in to NUnit. You have a few options: You could try a different assertions library (FluentAssertions, Shouldly, ... ) and see if there is any you like better. Otherwise, you could also create a PR on NUnit and add it. I think it could be rather complex though as you have to take into account omissions, extras and the order. If all 3 are wrong it'd be difficult to print a decent statement.

Comment: The need has been discussed in this NUnit issue: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1151 Some ideas of how to do it as well as an eventual PR would be quite welcome.

Comment: I'll consider writing a PR as soon as my team switches to NUnit 3.x. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will get you the desired result:

```
var a = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
var b = new[] { "b", "a", "d" };
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent( a, b,  "a is Missing " + string.Join( ", ", b.Except( a ) ) + " and b is missing " +
   string.Join( ", ", a.Except( b ) ));
```

Comment: There's some Linq in there that might have different equality semantics. Also, the message doesn't read as nice. For example, there are no double-quotes around the printed elements when they are strings. Nifty little details...

Comment: @Dejan but I figured you would know how to add those minor details.

Comment: I even figured that with Linq `Except` I can get that extra info. That's why I was asking specifically about a NUnit solution. To save myself the work. Just to see if I was missing something.

Comment: Actually using `Except` is *wrong*. Consider: `a = new[] { "a", "a", "b" }` and `b = new[] { "a", "b" }`. The error message created with `Except` will say that there is no missing and no extra element (which is wrong). `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` will rightfully fail.

Comment: It's not wrong. That is how 'Except'  works. It looks for string 'a'  in and uses the default equality comparer for a string. It finds 'a'  in both so it doesn't complain. If order is important to you then see if 'Except'  has an overload or write a custom method.

Comment: I'm not saying that `Except` is wrong. I'm saying that the error message created using `Except` is wrong. Or at least misleading.

Comment: Got it. Sorry my bad ;)

Comment: If order is important to you, don't use equivalence, which ignores order. Use an equality test.